# Regret minimization for online convex optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm reading the paper ["Online Convex Programming and Generalized Infinitesimal Gradient Ascent"](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrecht/cs294docs/week1/03.Zinkevich.pdf) (Zhinkevich,  2003) that talks about gradient descent and its properties in the online convex setting, and I am stuck with two questions:

1. I cannot see how the proof of Theorem 1 uses the fact that $x^*$ is the minimizer of $C_x(T)$. It seems that we can replace $x^*$ with any other point in the domain and still get the bound.
2. This is a more general question about bounding the regret. Does it tell us anything about convergence? If all $c_t$ in this paper were the same, then I can see that the regret is always non-negative, hence, sublinear bound on it guarantees convergence in some sense. But if $c_t$ are different (so the regret can be negative), can we conlude anything from this bound?

Thanks in advance!